# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.ngtsc(2339)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

[image]Getting this weird issue in my template please take a look if this can be resolved. I tried some answers related to this but i got nothing.

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signUpForm = new FormGroup({
      'userName': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      'gender': new FormControl('male'),
      'hobbies': new FormArray([])
    })
  }

  onAddHobby() {
    const control = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
    (<FormArray>this.signUpForm.get('hobbies')).push(control);
  }
```

```html
 <div formArrayName="hobbies">
    <h4>your hobbies</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="onAddHobby()">add hobby</button>
    <div
      class="form-group"
      *ngFor="
        let hobbyControl of signUpForm.get('hobbies').controls;
        let i = index
      "
    >
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `signUpForm.controls['hobbies']`?

Comment: no it's not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the `get()` method returns an `AbstractControl`, which doesn't have the controls property.

To solve it you can add a getter in the class to cast the control to a `FormArray`

```
get hobbies(): FormArray {
  return this.signUpForm.get('hobbies') as FormArray;
}
```

And then use the getter in the template instead as:

```
<div 
  class="form-group"
  *ngFor="
    let hobbyControl of hobbies.controls;
    let i = index
  "
>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to solve:

```
let hobbyControl of $any(signUpForm.get('hobbies')).controls;
```

The compiler is complaining because `signUpForm.get('hobbies')` returns an `abstractControl` (which doesn't have controls), but since you know that this is a `FormArray` you can use `$any()` https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#any-type-cast-function

Comment: Thanks! this is working but this is a good approach to fix this or not?

Comment: Hello, @Zerotwelve. I rejected your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30989549), because you are trying to add code highlighting by adding `\`\`\` language`, but this adds extra space indentation to the whole code block. You can use `<!-- language: yaml -->` instead, or remove extra spaces manually.